# Creating a makefile for CUDA programs

Tags: makefile, nvcc

I want to automate the compilation of a toy library using CUDA and C++. Then I write a Makefile as follows

```
CC=g++
NVCC=nvcc
CXXFLAGS= -fopenmp -O3 -Wextra -std=c++11
CUDAFLAGS= -std=c++11 -c -arch=sm_20
LIBS= -lopenblas -lpthread -lcudart -lcublas
LIBDIRS=-L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
INCDIRS=-I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include
matrix_cuda.o: marix_cuda.cu
     $(NVCC) $(CUDAFLAGS)   matrix_cuda.cu
all: matrix_cuda.o
        $(CC) -o test matrix_blas.cpp alg.cpp test.cpp matrix_cuda.o $(LIBDIRS) $(INCDIRS) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -rf test *.o
```

Typing `make` I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `marix_cuda.cu', needed by `matrix_cuda.o'.  Stop.
```

I never wrote a Makefile before. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How would you build the library using the command line, without Make?

Comment: `nvcc -std=c++11 -c -arch=sm_20   matrix_cuda.cu` and then `g++ -o test matrix_blas.cpp alg.cpp test.cpp matrix_cuda.o -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64  -I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include -lopenblas -lpthread -lcudart -lcublas  -fopenmp -O3 -Wextra -std=c++11`

Comment: please try from this tutorial/example: https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vStJ4SiboX3JeoPpNxnNS6kr8UB-SurWjqvSUUVd9dCmEOcjGZMQGhQicAFItnlwjr165BAEEVU3JQ_/pub

Answer (score 8):

I think you have a typo in the CUDA file name

```
matrix_cuda.o: marix_cuda.cu
     $(NVCC) $(CUDAFLAGS)   matrix_cuda.cu
```

IMHO it should be

```
matrix_cuda.o: matrix_cuda.cu
     $(NVCC) $(CUDAFLAGS)   matrix_cuda.cu
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is clearly a typo, and the error message says exactly that!

Answer (score 3):

This may take a couple of iterations.

1) First try this:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -c -arch=sm_20 matrix_cuda.cu
```

If that works (and produces `matrix_cuda.o`, I presume), remove `matrix_cuda.o` and

2) try this makefile:

```
matrix_cuda.o: matrix_cuda.cu
    nvcc -std=c++11 -c -arch=sm_20 matrix_cuda.cu
```

If that works,

3) try this:

```
g++ -o test matrix_blas.cpp alg.cpp test.cpp matrix_cuda.o -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 -I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include -lopenblas -lpthread -lcudart -lcublas -fopenmp -O3 -Wextra -std=c++11
```

If that works, remove `test` and

4) try this makefile:

```
test: matrix_cuda.o
    g++ -o test matrix_blas.cpp alg.cpp test.cpp matrix_cuda.o -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 -I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include -lopenblas -lpthread -lcudart -lcublas -fopenmp -O3 -Wextra -std=c++11

matrix_cuda.o: matrix_cuda.cu
    nvcc -std=c++11 -c -arch=sm_20 matrix_cuda.cu
```

If that works, remove `test` and `matrix_cuda.o` and

5) try that makefile again.

If that works, there are further refinements we can make.

Comment: It stops at step 2). I typed `make all` and then `make: *** No rule to make target marix_cuda.cu, needed by matrix_cuda.o.  Stop.`

Comment: @pateheo: Is `matrix_cuda.cu` present in the working directory (the directory you are in)?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add some commentary on this Makefile for future reference and better automation :

1. `NVCC=nvcc` environment variable is superfluous. There is only one compiler for NVIDIA GPUs and you would nonetheless have to change a lot of flags to compile for other architectures like AMD.

2. `-arch=native` is better suited if you want to deploy your code on multiple machines with GPUs having different architectures
3. `-dc` is the flag for separate compilation. The architecture must be specified before `-dc` see (with a generic Makefile): https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/
4. You should add automatic rule to avoid these typos errors :

```
%.o: %.cu
     nvcc -dc $(CUDAFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The Makefile will look for all dependencies ending by `.o`. If it needs to build one, it looks if it has the corresponding .cu file. I would actually remove the -dc from flags and be explicit here that I want to build object files.
$@ is the name of the rule target. $< is the first prerequisite. Only one file at a time can be passed to nvcc with the `-dc` flag, so here $< is better than $^.

5. You may add the name of the executable in a variable so that you delete the same executable that you generated (and facilitate name change).
6. I added a .PHONY rule. This only removes the confusion that happens whenever someone writes a file named `clean` in the directory.
   The Makefile can not differenciate between the file and the `make clean` rule.

```
CC=g++
CXXFLAGS= -fopenmp -O3 -Wextra -std=c++11
CUDAFLAGS= -std=c++11 -arch=sm_20
LIBS= -lopenblas -lpthread -lcudart -lcublas
LIBDIRS=-L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
INCDIRS=-I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include
PROGRAM= test
%.o: %.cu
     nvcc -dc $(CUDAFLAGS) $< -o $@
all: matrix_cuda.o
        $(CC) -o $(PROGRAM) matrix_blas.cpp alg.cpp test.cpp matrix_cuda.o $(LIBDIRS) $(INCDIRS) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM) *.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your first make rule corresponds to compiling the object file `matrix_cuda.o`. The `all` make rule should come first since the first rule in the make file is the one that gets updated first when invoking the command `make`. GNU Make has great documentation explaining how to make simple to complex makefiles. You can check it out here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html.

Also another issue you are going to run into is that in your make recipe for the `all` rule, you are supposed to be linking together only object files to create the final executable. However you are trying to include `matrix_blas.cpp alg.cpp test.cpp` in this linking step. Instead of `.cpp` versions of these files they need to be `.o` versions (the compiled objects). `Make` can generate these object files for you. You just need to have a make rule and recipe for each one. For example:

```
matrix_blas.o: matrix_blas.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c matrix_blas.cpp -o matrix_blas.o
```